# Undirected Connected Graph : Number of unique path

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees, recursive-algorithms

Given an undirected connected graph with $N$ nodes and $N-1$ edges, a path $P_1P_2\cdots P_i$ is defined as follows:

1. Nodes $P_j$ and $P_{j+1}$ are connected by an edge for each $\left({1}\right) <= \left({j}\right) <= \left({i}\right)$;
2. The weight of a $Pth$ node is given as $P_k$;
3. The number of indices $j$ with $\left({1}\right) < \left({j}\right) < \left({i}\right)$ such that $\left(P_{k_{j-1}}\right) < \left(P_{k_{j}}\right)$ and $\left(P_{k_{j}}\right) > \left(P_{k_{j+1}}\right)$ is at least *Min* and at most *Max* for some given *Min* and *Max*;
4. Any node should not be repeated in that sequence ;

How many such paths are there?

Comment: Please use MathJax when formatting your question. See http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: @user259242 Sorry,I will make sure to use it.

Comment: Your graph is a tree. I think that the answer depends on the graph shape, weights of its vertices, and given values of $Min$ and $Max$.

Comment: Can someone please explain the second condition in detail?

Comment: @AlexRavsky I fixed the question. Please check it out again. And the shape ,weight of it's vertices and value of $Min$ and $Max$ are given.

Comment: @ShinKim There was a error in th edit done by someone. They probably misunderstood which leads to the wrong explanation of the second condition. Please check out the question again.

Comment: @hardmath There was a error in the second condition because of the edit by someone else. Please check the condition again. It is clear now.

Comment: I see that the inequalities of your condition now involve "weights" of nodes, rather than their degrees.  However I still cannot see that anything nontrivial can be said about counting the paths of one type (given $Min$ and $Max$).  The total number of paths altogether (without regard to counting local maxima) is still $N\cdot (N-1)$.

Comment: @hardmath The answer will be different because for any path there are $j $ indices such that the second condition will be satisified. See, now the value of $j$ should be between $Min$ and $Max$. So there should be at least $1$ such path satisfying the second condition.

Comment: @sammy 1. I looked the edits done after I last saw the question  and it seems for me that they messed weights of vertices with their names, because both are denoted by $P_j$. Please clarify the question and remove unnecessary brackets.  

2. So you are asking for  an algorithm which calculates the number of paths given the graph, weights of its vertices, and values of $Min$ and $Max$?

Comment: @AlexRavsky First the list of nodes is given by $P_1......P_i$. The weight of any $Pth$ node is $P_k$. Now in this list for a $jth$ Node which is in between $1$ and $i$ , its weight will be  $(P_{k_{j}}\ )$ . And yes is I'm asking the algorithm given all the things with the condition mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Without specific conditions imposed on the shape of the graph $G$, weights $w(v)$ of its nodes $v$, the given  values $Min$ and $Max$ I can propose a straightforward algorithm, which has a complexity polynomial with the respect to the number of nodes of the graph $G$.

Let $v$ and $u$ be arbitrary nodes of the graph $G$. Let the number of peaks $p(v,u)$ be the number of indices $j$, ($1<j<i$) such that $w(v_{j-1})< w(v_{j})< w(v_{j+1})$, where $v=v_0,v_1\dots, v_{i-1}, v_{k}=u$ is the unique simple path between these nodes.

First of all we do a preprocessing which calculates the number of peaks $p(v,u)$ on the simple path between each pair $v$ and $u$ of nodes of the graph $G$ and the first node $n(v,u)$ on these path. This can be done recursively as follows. Let $v$ be a leaf of the graph $G$. Calculate the number of peaks and the first node on the simple path between each pair of nodes of the induced graph $G - v$. Let $u$ be a unique neighbor of the node $v$. Put $n(v,u)=u$, $n(u,v)=v$, and for each node $u’\ne u$ of the graph  $G- v$ put $n(u’,v)=n(u’,u)$,  $n(v,u’)=u$, and 
$$p(u’,v)=\cases{p(u’,u)+1, \mbox{if $w(v)<w(u)>w(n(v,u’))$},\\ 
p(u’,u), \mbox{otherwise}}.$$

Now the quantity which you are asking for is the number $N$ of pair $\{v,u\}$ of nodes of the graph $G$ such that

$$Min\le p(v,u)\le Max.$$